# RewriteRule messing up 301 redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am in the process of rebuilding my entire website, the previous version used only static html pages and was a nightmare to manage.

In the new site I already have a `.htaccess` with the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MySite/?q=$1
```

It rewrites URLs via PHP.

However, what I also need to do is add lines like this:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.mysite.com/dir/newpage.html
Redirect 301 /oldpage2.html http://www.mysite.com/dir/newpage2.html
Redirect 301 /oldpage3.html http://www.mysite.com/dir/newpage3.html
```

The URL directory structure of my site has completely changed, I have a lot of pages indexed in google and need to 301 them to the new URL.

I've tried adding these new 301 directives to the end of my existing `.htaccess` but then I end up being redirected like this:

http://www.mysite.com/dir/newpage.html?q=oldpage.html

I don't want it to have the query string on the end, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them before the main redirect with `L` directive:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^oldpage\.html$ /dir/newpage.html [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^oldpage2\.html$ /dir/newpage2.html [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MySite/?q=$1
```